# FOSUserbundle: Redirect on accessing Admin section

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a normal FOSUserBundle installed in my Symfony project.
What I'm intending to do is provide my admin section further security by making it unknown to the public. What I want to do is throw a 404 error whenever somebody who is not an Admin tries to access the section directly, so nobody even knows at which address it is at, to prevent hacking attempts in the core.
I set up an ExceptionListener, which works fine:

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();

        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');

        $response = new Response($templating->render('ScatternoteBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig', array(
            'exception' => $exception
        )));

        $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

From my error404.html.twig:

```
{% if 'No route found for' not in exception.message and exception.message != 'Impossible to access an attribute ("album") on a NULL variable ("") in "ScatternoteBundle:Song:song.html.twig" at line 3' and 'Access Denied' not in exception.message%}
    <span style="font-size:8pt; color:grey;">Not a 404: {{ exception.message }}; Code: {{ exception.code }}</span>
        <br><br>
    {% endif %}
```

However, it only works when one is logged in **as a user**. If I'm not logged in and try to access /admin, I am redirected automatically to /login by the FOSUserBundle. I've done a lot of research, however I couldn't find any information on how to stop this from happening, or where this event is actually handled in the bundle.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

EDIT: My security.yaml:

```
security:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
  fos_userbundle:
       id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
# the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
# for specific sections of your app
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    # the login page has to be accessible for everybody
    demo_login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false
    main:
                        pattern: ^/
                        form_login:
                            provider: fos_userbundle
                            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                        logout:       true
                        anonymous:    true


    # secures part of the application
    demo_secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        # it's important to notice that in this case _demo_security_check and _demo_login
        # are route names and that they are specified in the AcmeDemoBundle
        form_login:
            check_path: _demo_security_check
            login_path: _demo_login
        logout:
            path:   _demo_logout
            target: _demo
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

# with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
# of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
access_control:
                - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I can only guess that you have set firewals in security.yaml, and those firewalls redirect unauthorized user to login form

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't set any firewalls in my security.yaml, it only contains the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

The login page has a public access so that's normal why FOSUser redirect user to login form (In order to access secured area). Also when a user access a secured area a 403 exception (access denied) is throw (not 404 not found).
I think you should override the register action of FOSUser in the RegistrationController:

```
if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
} else {
throw new AccessDeniedException ('Oups !!! Access denied ' ) ;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you are aiming at. I want to stop FOSUser from redirecting me to the Login page if I try to access a secured area and am not logged in, so unlogged users are treated the same as logged users. I don't understand what that's got to do with registration.

Comment: that's what im saying override the controller when fos user redirect you to login page and redirect it to another page or throw an axception

Comment: But where is it redirecting me from /admin to /login? Certainly not in the RegistrationController. If I'm mistaken, please tell me where, because then I'm obviously too dumb to see...

Comment: In the loginAction of security controlleryou will find renderLogin there you can change the view (from login to a custom view ) or change the route and redirect to your own route

Comment: That would mean overriding the login action, which I don't want to do. I don't want to turn my login into a 404 page, because then nobody could log in, just delete the redirection.

Comment: Im just giving you an idea then you can do whatever you want ^^ i hope that you found the solution.